# Why does 'Link Time Optimization' results in larger binaries?

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, compiler-optimization

When I enable Link Time Optimization in GCC, the binaries produced become much larger. I expected GCC to be able to remove a lot of reduntant functions, and perform other optimizations otherwise impossible, so how come this makes the generated output grow?

Compiler flags:

```
-Os -c -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb
```

Linker flags:

```
-nostdlib -s -Xlinker --gc-sections -flto -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -T
```

Comment: How exactly are you using `-flto`? Show the compilation commands.... And gives us more details (compiler version). Did you try with a recent GCC (i.e. 4.9.1 on september 2014)?

Comment: If you use -O3 (make faster but bigger code), LTO gives the compiler more opportunities to make the code faster (and bigger). If you use -Os (make small binaries), LTO gives you more opportunities to shrink the code size.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks, but I already use the -Os option, otherwise the firmware won't fit in 64kb at all.

Comment: @Muis First, those flags (and the gcc version, things have been changing a lot lately) should have been included in your original post. Second, no, from what you posted (truncated command lines so I have to guess a bit) you are not using -Os (not where it really matters).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Those flags are automaticly generated by the IDE im using (LPCXPresso), so that makes it hard to proivde a full commandline or determine the gcc version easily. But can you give an example on how to use '-Os' correctly?

Comment: Maybe a late response, but my binary actually shrinks by this flag (a lot!). It goes from 10.9MB to 1.7MB just by adding this flag to the compiler and the linker. I didn't believe at first and rebuild without the flag and indeed the size was again 10.9MB.

Comment: @MichielUitHetBroek It turned out it was a bug in my IDE (LPCXpresso), the flag works for me too.

Comment: @MarcGlisse -O3 doesn't make faster code. In fact it can even produce slower code. See also this talk: https://youtu.be/r-TLSBdHe1A?si=zgw4CrWxHqi-g7Tc&t=1421

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you strip the binary after linking with `-flto` (it should be provided both at compilation and at link time)?

BTW, notice [that](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) **the *same optimization* flags (`-flto -Os`) should be passed *both* at compile time *and* at link time.** If you forgot -like you did- any of them at linking phase, LTO won't work! (When using `make` you want `CC=gcc -flto -Os` not `CFLAGS= -flto -Os`).

<sup>You did forgot `-Os` at *link* time, in *addition* of `-flto`; just passing `-flto` at link time without any optimizations is wrong: the LTO phase would "de-optimize" at most</sup>

I know that `-flto` adds a lot of sections in the ELF object files and executables (those sections contain the serialization of GCC internal representations like Gimple....). I guess (but have not checked) that the linking does not remove them.

Also, the main point of LTO is to *inline* accross *several compilation units* and this is expected to grow the code. So perhaps you should not use LTO in your particular case.

Most redundant functions are already removed (by the linker "GC" on sections) even without LTO.

BTW, you could use `objdump`or `readelf`to find out.

Comment: Yes, I used to the '-s' option of the linker (Omit all debug information). My firmware normally fits in 64 kb, but with '-ftlo' it almost doubles in size.

Comment: *LTO* is a new feature of GCC.  Both the *gold* (new linker) version and the *gcc* version will influence code generation.  You **should** provide the linker with the same optimization options as you compile with.  This is a change with *LTO* that some people are not aware of.  The `-O3` is not to optimize for size but performance.  If you really want size, you should try `-Os` for both compile and link.

Comment: @Muis You should try to strip the binaries explictly by using the `strip` command.

Comment: @artlessnoise I already used -Os for compiling, but how do I specify that setting to the linker?

Comment: @Masta79 The linker aborts with the message that the binary will not fit in the flash region (64kb), so there's no output binary to strip. I think I can enlarge the region to fake I have more flash, but I'm not sure what will happen if I flash such a binary to the device.

Comment: @muis To specify `-Os` to the linker, add `-Os` to the linker flags.  Basile's answer is exactly right; this has to do with forgetting to tell the linker the optimization flags.  It is not related to the debug info or stripping the binary.

Comment: @JimParis I tried it, and it didnt make a change. When I specify '-ftlo' for the compiler OR the linker, i get a normal sized binary. When I specify '-ftlo' for the compiler AND the linker, the result is a couple of kilobytes larger.

Comment: But you should expect LTO to increase the binary executable size!

Comment: How are you determining that it is larger?  Use `size foo.elf` to get the right value.  Also, it looks like you're running the linker directly; I don't think this is recommended, use gcc as a frontend (which means you'll have `-Wl,--gc-sections` instead of `--gc-sections`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you have a source that says -Os is a valid option for a (any) linker?

Answer (score 0):

Important thing for LTO is the working linker plugin support. Only with that GCC can make agressive unreachable code removal and other optimizaitons. Be sure you have plugin enabled linker (just try if LTO linking works with -fuse-linker-plugin)

Comment: Yes, I already solved the problem. It was a bug in my IDE (LPXPresso), where the setting only applied to the compiler, not the linker.